# A bug in my manual mipmap generation

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, shader

My code was working correctly, until I started to add a new feature that took an existing texture and generated high mip levels for it. After this code, I do not use the higher mip levels at all, I set the base and max mip level to 0, and thus should only be using the original texture. However, I get buggy artifacts if I use the following mip generation code. **Again, I don't even use the higher mip levels**,  just the fact that I generate the higher mip levels seems to mess up the lowest mip level.

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, workFrame) ;
glUseProgram(ShaderPrograms.HiZData.theProgram);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + ShaderPrograms.HiZData.Cache.lastMipBindingIndex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, worldDepth);
glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS);
for(int i = 1; i<numLevels; i++) {
    glViewport(0, 0, depthDims.get(i).x, depthDims.get(i).y);
    // bind next level for rendering but first restrict fetches only to previous level
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, i  - 1);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, i - 1);
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, worldDepth, i);
    // draw full-screen quad
    Quad2D.renderFullScreenNDCquad();
}
glViewport(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
```

I can comment out the line that renders the full screen quad, which is the call that does glDraw and actually does the writing to the miplevels, and everything will be correct and normal.

Any help please?

EDIT: I can fix it if comment out these lines:

```
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

why?

Comment: One thing that surprises me is that you attach the texture level you want to render to `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT`. Is that on purpose? If yes, do you set `gl_FragDepth` in your fragment shader to write the desired value to it, i.e. the value you obtained from sampling the previous texture level? Are you sure that you don't also have something bound to GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, and accidentally write values to that?

Comment: I was initially also suspicious about your use of `glFramebufferTexture` instead of the more common (at least to me) `glFramebufferTexture2D`. But after some spec reading, I believe the two should be equivalent for this case.

Comment: @RetoKoradi yes, gl_FragDepth is set in the fragment shader. Nothing is bound to color attachment for this frame, but even if there was, it wouldn't explain my bug. I've tried glFramebufferTexture2D also and that didn't work either, I think you are correct, they are equivalent.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I fixed it somehow.. but how? look at my edit

Comment: So, for one thing I don't see a single line where you actually allocate storage for ***any*** of your texture images; not LOD **0** or `numLevels - 1`. Include any relevant calls to `glTexImage2D (...)` or `glTexStorage2D (...)`. Also, `GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL` is a **sampling** parameter; you are not trying to sample this texture (I hope), only writing to it - so that is unnecessary. What ***is*** important is the image LOD you attach to your FBO.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it... I think you ***are*** trying to sample from the same texture you're drawing into. Don't do that unless you use a texture barrier.